# UINavigationController not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, animation, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to get the slide animation that occurs with a `UINavigationController`.

All of the `UINavigationController` setup examples involve using multiple `XIB`'s for different views, however all my views are `UIViewControllers` in one `XIB`.

So far, I'm using `[self presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES];`, which works perfectly fine.

All of my view controllers are connected through `IBOutlets` to the main `XIB`.

Example :

```
#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
...
IBOutlet MyViewController *myViewController;
//connected through Interface Builder
...
}
```

And in `Interface Builder`:
[image]

I thought I could use something like:

```
UINavigationController *myNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self] autorelease];
[myNavController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

However that does absolutely nothing.

I'm a bit stuck on this.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: We need to see a bit more code than this - where is "myViewController" instantiated for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the view of the `UINavigationController` to your view hierarchy at some place.
In the Xcode template *Navigation-based Application* this done by adding it to the `UIWindow`:

```
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

Comment: Is it the UIWindow that's created in the AppDelegate?

Comment: It is the outlet of the AppDelegate which is created when the first NIB is loaded.

Comment: Ok I get a blank view to load when I push the button - pushing back doesn't return to the previous controller but to a white screen.

Comment: Is the naivigationController the rootViewController of the window?

Answer (score 0):

I've cracked it after looking at [Apple's UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) documentation.

I created a `UINavigationController` in my Application's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method like so:

```
UIViewController *dcview = [[DocumentationViewController alloc] init];
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                        initWithRootViewController:dcview];
[dcview release];
navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

and then calling

```
[((DocumentationAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).navigationController pushViewController:settingsView animated:YES];
```

to push it.